# How to fix the AudioTrack: releaseBuffer() track 0xb4d4db00 disabled due to previous underrun, restarting

Tags: java, android

I am writing the a phone call function during the remote control. 
It should be turn to my incoming call pages , but when i recieve a call , it will output **"AudioTrack: releaseBuffer() track 0xb4d4db00 disabled due to previous underrun, restarting"** . How can i fix it ??

The function can handle the call but can not change the pages.

**Here is apart of code**

```
  public void onIncomingCall(VoiceCall call) {

    PermissionUtils.unregisterDelegate(mRecordAudioDelegate);

    mRemoteViewInitized = false;

    mRemoteView.disconnect();


    mRemoteView.setCallback(null);


    mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);


    RemoteContact callerContact = call.getIncomingCallerContact();

    Log.d(TAG,"failed");

    activeCallId = call.getCallId();



    if (callerContact != null) {
      number =callerContact.getDisplayName()  +" "+
              callerContact.getFirstDisplayNumber();
    }else{
      number = call.getRemoteUserNumber();
    }

    // updateTextView(call);
    mLoginClient = MbaClientApp.getInstance(MbaRemoteControlActivity.this).getLoginClient();

    final LcLoginClient.LcService service =
            mLoginClient.getService(PACKAGE_NAME_VOICE_CALL_SERVER);

    if (service != null) {


      Intent intent =
              new Intent(MbaRemoteControlActivity.this, IncomingCall.class);

      intent.putExtra(
              IncomingCall.INTENT_KEY_INT_VOICE_CALL_PORT,
              Integer.valueOf(service.get(LcLoginClient.LcService.Key.KEY_PORT)));

      intent.putExtra(
              IncomingCall.INTENT_KEY_INT_VOICE_CALL_HOST,
              serverHost);
      intent.putExtra("host", mHost);
      intent.putExtra("call", activeCallId);
      intent.putExtra("phone", number);

      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

      startActivity(intent);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please add your code as well.

Comment: i had added my code on top

Comment: Did you find what was wrong?